# how to get length of list received in ajax response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

i am receiving `list` of objects in Ajax success response, now i want to calculate `size` of that array/ object. how to get it ?

**code:**

```
success: function (result) 
                {
              //  alert("back to succes.!");
                  $('#status').text("");   
                 var mera_obj = result.key;  
                 contents = mera_obj;
             }
```

Comment: how does the `result` looks like.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture the length of the returned `result`.

```
var sizeOfArrray = result.length;
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's an array, `array.length`, if it's an object, `Object.keys(object).length`, or iterating in older browsers.
You can join both methods with something like :

```
var mera_obj = result.key,
    contents = mera_obj,

    size = Array.isArray(result) ? result.length : Object.keys(result).length;
```

As `result` is accessed with `result.key`, it's probably an object, as dot notation doesn't work well with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

i have modified @adeneo's answer:

```
var sizeOfArrray = Array.isArray(result.key) ? result.key.length : Object.keys(result.key).length;
```

its working.!